# Troubleshoot performance?

Tags: interface, performance, command-line

Are there any tools or options to help troubleshoot performance? When using blender, every few seconds I get a split-second of lag. This interrupts any smooth movements, like transforms, or scrubbing sliders and gets very irritating. I assume the problem is related to a script or addon, but I have a ton of those. I also get a bunch of dependency cycle and constraint errors popping up in my console, so it could also be one of those areas (but the rig isn't actually in use, and I've had the same rig for ages and this problem is new.)

I can of course start trying to figure it out through trial and error (turning things off and seeing when it goes away, then turning them back on until it comes back), but i'd also like to know if there's any tools to help with that. I need to figure out which script is causing it, or what part of my rig(s) is doing something when it shouldn't. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: My suggestion is to focus on the covid dependencies. They are most likely what causes the lag, and they can really screw up any animation

Comment: Can't edit on tablet. Cyclic, not covid ofc.

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz None of them should actually be real dependency cycles. I'm using Cloth Sim and collision objects. Some items have both. It seems to be listing garments that have both as being dependency cycles with each other, even though this is normal use of cloth sim. There's a lot of places where it mis-identifies dependency cycles, like it can get confused between objects and data.

Comment: Since you found the dep. cycles, I assume you have opened the console? Does the lag include the mouse cursor? Does it only happen in that project? Does it happen when you play your animation, but leave the mouse alone? Context is important here.

Comment: I'd have to badly mistaken if you can mix a "regular" collision with a cloth sim on the same object. How is this supposed to be calculated, which cloth object gets first deformed and then collides and which one collides first and then deforms.

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz Cloth sim does not use the regular Collision on itself within the same object. It uses its own self collision for that. But it does use it for colliding with other objects. As for the specifics of the troubleshooting, I wanted the question to be in general, not get into the specifics of my file and addon setup.

Comment: Dependency cycles are general. I'm pretty sure that's the issue here. If I understand you correctly, you used the object collision (the one right above cloth sim in the physics tab) in combination with the cloth sim. IDK why they give you the option to do so, but it cannot work.

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz That's the only way to make cloth collide with another object. I've used this method on tons of projects and never had any issues from it. Its the standard way taught in all cloth sim tutorials.